# Ethernet problem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ethernet

pardon my total lack of knowledge as I'm a first time user of Ubuntu. I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 in a machine which already runs Windows 7 HB. I have an ethernet connection which I use to be online. After booting ubuntu and trying to access the internet, I see the message on the right telling me that LAN is connected. But, when I try to access any webpage on firefox, it just doesn't load. Also, I've pinged www.google.com, which gives me an error, "Unknown Host".

Please Help.

Thanks in anticipation.

P.S: I'm a rookie so please give me steps to check if you're asking for any thing specific.

Comment: Are you using a gateway modem/router/wifi or just a modem? What brand

Comment: unplug your cable modem and power down your PC for 30 seconds, then turn your modem back on and start up to Ubuntu.

Comment: @damien I've got a cable which is connected to a router, and the router is present in the terrace of my apartment building.

Comment: @Deryck I should "Shut Down" my Windows 7 and not Hibernate it. Right?

Comment: Do you have a dual boot environment?  You never did say if your Windows 7 machine functions correctly or not.  Have you checked to see if you can ping via IP number?  Are you aware of how to setup or Linux network fundamentals?

Comment: Can you give us output from `nm-tool` `ifconfig -a` and `route -n`

Comment: @mdpc Yes, I'm sorry to not state it earlier. I have a dual boot environment. I have Ubuntu 14.10 along with Windows 7 HB running on the same machine. Also, I've tried pinging the following address on my Windows 7 HB:
www.google.com,
192.168.2.1,
192.168.2.1,
8.8.8.8,
www.facebook.com

The ping yield the same result for all the above addresses: 
Request Timed out (4 times, with 100% packet loss).

Comment: @meccooll
nm-tool:
NetworkManager Tool

`State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Ethernet connection 1] ----------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        D4:BE:D9:40:32:33

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.137.87
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.137.1

    DNS:             192.168.137.1`

Comment: Guess what guys, I booted the Ubuntu OS and created a new Ethernet connection through Configure VPN, and WOW!! It's connected and I'm commenting this through Ubuntu. Thanks for your incessant support.